# How do you create LVM snapshot after the error message "not found: device not cleared"

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm trying to test LVM, but I failed on first, potentially simple task - create a snapshot.

I have following situation:

```
root@debian:~# vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  big    1   1   0 wz--n- 14.99g 5.68g
  fast   1   2   0 wz--n- 14.99g 4.75g
```

and

```
root@debian:~# lvs
  Internal error: Using string as sort value for numerical field.
  Internal error: Using string as sort value for numerical field.
  Internal error: Using string as sort value for numerical field.
  LV   VG   Attr     LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  home big  -wi-ao--   9.31g                                           
  root fast -wi-ao--   9.31g                                           
  swap fast -wi-ao-- 952.00m
```

I'd like to make test snapshot of home, so Figured this will be the command to use:

```
lvcreate --size 1G -n snap -s /dev/big/home
```

But it fails with:

```
/dev/big/snap: not found: device not cleared
Aborting. Failed to wipe snapshot exception store.
```

Well, obviously there is no /dev/big/snap - I didn't make the snapshot yet.

/dev/big contains only link to home:

```
root@debian:~# ls -l /dev/big/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov 28 18:09 home -> ../dm-2
```

What am I missing in here?

Comment: While searching fro answer, I found this: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=343671 - but it didn't help either, as I didn't have the files mentioned there. So finally I made apt-get update and upgrade, and the problem went away. Not sure what caused it, but snapshotting works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lvcreate command looks fine.  One thing that will cause this error is if udev isn't running.  Try `service udev status` to see if it's running, and `service udev start` if it's not.

Comment: udev is running, and was running. rebooted, restarted, still the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me during a dist-upgrade from Debian 7 Wheezy to Debian 8 Jessie, too, where the `udev` package was already upgraded, but the `lvm2` wasn't yet. Upgrading the `lvm2` package helped and the `lvmcreate` command worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after a failed `vgimportclone` run. The solution was to make sure the affected volume group was inactive (`vgchange -a n`) and then to manually remove all those leftover broken symlinks.

Note that deactivation of volume groups may be foiled by bugs such as https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1088081